# Link in SVG image disappearing when resize browser

Tags: html, css, svg, webbrowser-control

I am working on a clickable human body svg so visitors can click the part they injured and they will be directed to the corresponding page, there is way too much code for the svg to add here so ill just add the top section:

```
<div class="svg">
<svg inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)" 
 sodipodi:docname="bodynew.svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 500 400" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" 
 xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd">
 <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1" fit-margin- 
 bottom="0" fit-margin-left="0" fit-margin-right="0" fit-margin-top="0" 
 gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:current-layer="svg4523" 
 inkscape:cx="260.76197" inkscape:cy="215.76186" inkscape:pageopacity="0" 
 inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-height="837" inkscape:window- 
 maximized="1" inkscape:window-width="1440" inkscape:window-x="-8" 
 inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:zoom="1.5571096" objecttolerance="10" 
 pagecolor="#ffffff" showgrid="false"/>
 <g>
 <a xlink:href="#0" class="svg" data-Name="shape 1" data-tabindex="0">
```

The css i am using is very straight forward, all it is doing is highlighting the links as the visitor hovers.

```
a.svg {
cursor: pointer;
}

a.svg:focus {
fill: pink;
stroke: red;
stroke-width: 1;
}
a.svg:hover {
fill: pink;
stroke: red;
stroke-width: 1;
}
```

This works just fine as expected but as soon as i change window size or move to mobile the links are no longer clickable so the hover capabilities are gone.

any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: This is unanswerable without a [mcve]. Try to create a simple example of an SVG that illustrates this issue, preferably without any of the code bloat added by Inkscape (i.e., remove all the `sodipodi` and `inkscape` tags/attributes). It would also help if you could describe what efforts you have made to solve the problem. Have you tried using a different browser?

Comment: thanks @squeamishossifrage code wise there is too much to add but you can see this live on the site http://dcphysiotherapy.ie/ and view the source code... you will also see here that when you change the size of any browser ( I have tried all) the links are again unclickable .

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what the exact problem is, but it looks like Bootstrap is causing the top padding of the `#pricing` section to extend over the entire SVG.

A quick fix would be to add the following CSS rule (after loading Bootstrap):

```
#pricing .container .row:first-child { pointer-events: none; }
```